# Slideshow gone haywire

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, slideshow

I have a slideshow that loops and everything but it doesn't work quite as I would expect.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/Mb5nR/1/

Jquery:

```
// Customisable

var gap = 3;
var duration = 0.6;

// Non Customisable

var g = gap * 1000;
var d = duration * 1000;
var loop = $('.slideshow img').length;
var loopDelay = 200;
var x = 1;
var i = 1;

while(i <= loop){
    $('.slideshow img:nth-child(' + x + ')').delay(g).fadeOut(d);
    x++;
    i++;
    $('.slideshow img:nth-child(' + x + ')').delay(g + loopDelay).fadeIn(d);
    var h = g;
    var g = x * h;
    var lD = loopDelay;
    var loopDelay = lD + 200;
}
```

What I think should happen is it will go through all of the elements starting a queue so they all fade in and out consecutively though they all do so at the same time and none fade in

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that jQuery uses multithreading for commands which affect the graphic display, so your fadeIn and fadeOut calls are being run in the background (in their own thread) while the main execution thread carries on to the next instruction **immediately**. So while your first image is fading out, the main thread is already telling the next image to fade in. And the next image, and the one after that, and so on. All at (more or less) exactly the same time.

What you need is the callback feature of commands like fadeIn and fadeOut. See [the jQuery API documentation page for fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and notice that an optional callback can be provided. This callback must be a function which will trigger only once the fadeOut has finished. You need to use this behaviour so that your script only continues after each fade has completed.

For example:

```
hideCurrentImage = new function() {
    $currentImage = //your code to select displayed image goes here
    $currentImage.fadeOut(d, showNextImage);
};

showNextImage = new function() {
    $nextImage = //your code to select next image from set goes here
    $nextImage.fadeIn(d, hideCurrentImage);
};
```

Using this mechanism will mean that images can only fade in and out one after the other, because each call to fadeIn and fadeOut specifies the callback function to use once the fade is completed. So you won't see them all load and fade at the same time.